# Unhandled rejection ServerlessError: An error occurred: IamRoleLambdaExecution - 1 validation error detected

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-cognito

I am creating a lambda function in AWS serverless application, but when I deploy the code I get this error:

> Unhandled rejection ServerlessError: An error occurred:
>   IamRoleLambdaExecution - 1 validation error detected: Value
>   'aws-node-rest-api-with-dynamodb-and-offline-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole'
>   at 'roleName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length
>   less than or equal to 64 (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status
>   Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID:
>   9ebd972c-b909-11e9-ac61-85855f5899bc).

Comment: This is the reason for the error: `'roleName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 64`

Comment: Notice also how I've reformatted and re-organized your question. You got to ask properly to get useful responses.

Answer (score 0):

Your role name, `aws-node-rest-api-with-dynamodb-and-offline-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole`, is too long. It needs to be less than 64-char in length.

Comment: Unhandled rejection ServerlessError: An error occurred: IamRoleLambdaExecution - API: iam:CreateRole User: arn:aws:iam::126478246000:user/popcorn_website is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::126478246000:role/aws-node-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole.

now i am getting this error

Comment: Looks like the user that's creating the role doesn't have permission to create IAM roles.